# TinyMCE and jQuery - attr() is returning an Object

Tags: jquery, tinymce, attr

**I've solved this by using data() instead of attr()**, but I'd still like to know if this is just me, and what's causing it:

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 and TinyMCE 3.5b3 (jQuery package). No other JS libraries.

This code outputs "string", and the anchor tag's href, as expected, when the link is clicked.

```
$('a.page_item_delete').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log(typeof $this.attr('href'));
    console.log($this.attr('href'));
});
```

When I activate TinyMCE on some textareas on the page, it outputs "Object" and, of course, attr() stops returning an expected value. I'm activating TinyMCE via:

> $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce(options);

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour with TinyMCE? Is there a known bug, or workaround? Why is TinyMCE apparently affecting unrelated HTML elements on the page?

Comment: i strongly advise people not to use the tinymce-jquery build, because it is pretty slwo when it comes to handling keystrokes. besides that ther might be additional bugs...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am having the same problem. It is being caused by the tinymce-jquery package overriding the attr and css methods of the jquery object. It seems (sadly) that the solution is to not use the jquery version of tinymce.

I haven't worked yet out why this wasn't a problem with jquery 1.6 and is a problem with 1.7.

Edit:

I was using the jquery plugin like this:

```
$('.wysiwyg', '#EditForm').tinymce({
    -- SETTING HERE
});
```

and now I have done the following to replicate the behavior I required when using the jquery plugin:

```
$('.wysiwyg', '#EditForm').each(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    var ed = new tinyMCE.Editor(id, {
    -- SETTINS HERE --          
    });
    ed.render();
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Update TinyMCE to the latest version and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

jquery 1.7.2 and tinymce 3.5b3 seems to work ok.

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same problem I updated TinyMCE editor (jQuery package) to 3.5.11 version and
the behavior of `attr()` method became normal. The main problem was to know that it's a conflict between TinyMCE and jQuery `attr()` method. I didn't understand this one at once.

The advice is just update the editor.