# Jquery unobtrusive validation doen't work when tinymce control is rendered on page(Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have simple validation for textbox on my cshtml page:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Subject)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Subject)
```

Without tinymce unobtrusive validation works just perfect, but when I adding tinymce control using: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailBody)` Page loads with no errors(I guess 1-st on-page-load validation is passed, because the same jquery.validate.js:449 lines executes few time with no errors thrown), but before postback when I call `$('#emailNotificationsForm').valid()` it's fails on jquery.validate.js:449 with message: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

My view model fields are:

```
[Required]
public string Subject { get; set; }
[UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
public string EmailBody { get; set; }
```

tinymce partial view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {

        $(function () {

            $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)').tinymce({

                script_url: '@Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")',
                theme: "advanced",
                height: "300",
                width: "600",
                verify_html: false,

                theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,&Font,fontselect,Size,fontsizeselect,|,image,code",
                theme_advanced_buttons2: false,
                theme_advanced_buttons3: false,
                theme_advanced_buttons4: false,

                theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location: false,
                theme_advanced_resizing: false,

                content_css: "@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")",
                convert_urls: false,

                body_class: "mceBodyClass"
            });

        });

    })();
</script>


@Html.TextArea(string.Empty, /* Name suffix */
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue /* Initial value */
)
```

Additionally when whole next section is commented validation also works fine:

```
@*(function () {

        $(function () {

            $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)').tinymce({

                script_url: '@Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")',
                theme: "advanced",
                height: "300",
                width: "600",
                verify_html: false,

                theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,&Font,fontselect,Size,fontsizeselect,|,image,code",
                theme_advanced_buttons2: false,
                theme_advanced_buttons3: false,
                theme_advanced_buttons4: false,

                theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location: false,
                theme_advanced_resizing: false,

                content_css: "@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")",
                convert_urls: false,

                body_class: "mceBodyClass"
            });

        });

    })(); *@
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery version of the TinyMCE has own .attr() method which hides JQuery's one. 
You can either update TinyMCE or use non-jquery version. ([TinyMCE and jQuery - attr() is returning an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996041/tinymce-and-jquery-attr-is-returning-an-object))